# Partial derivative of $\beta^TX^TX\beta$ with respect to a component of $\beta$

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Suppose $X$ is a $n$ by $p$ matrix and $\beta$ is a $p$ dimensional vector, I want to know if the partial derivative of $\beta^TX^TX\beta$ with respect to $\beta_i$ of $\beta$ given by $2 \sum_{j=1}^p(X_{j,i})^2\beta_i$, where $\beta_i$ is a component of $\beta$?

The approach I took assumes that $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta_1} = \frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta } \cdot \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \beta_1}$, where $Z$ is $\beta^TX^TX\beta$. However, I am not sure if using the chain rule here in the context of matrix calculus is correct or not.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 Is this clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute this by expanding the product:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_i} [\beta^\top X^\top X \beta] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_i} \sum_{j, k} \beta_j [X^\top X]_{j, k} \beta_k \\
&= \sum_{j, k} \left( \delta_{i, j} [X^\top X]_{j, k} \beta_k + \beta_j [X^\top X]_{j, k} \delta_{i, k} \right) \\
&= \sum_k [X^\top X]_{i, k} \beta_k + \sum_j \beta_j [X^\top X]_{j, i} \\
&= 2 [X^\top X \beta]_i
\end{align*}
$$
since $[X^\top X]_{j, i} = [X^\top X]_{i, j}$ from the symmetry of $X^\top X$.

Comment: Hi, what is $\delta_{i, k}$ here?

Comment: That is the Kronecker delta (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), $\delta_{i, j} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

So you can use matrix/vector calculus in particular
$$
\frac{\partial(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}} = \left(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^T\right)\mathbf{x}
$$
so if we define $\mathbf{\beta} = \mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{A} =\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$
we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\beta^TX^TX\beta = (X^TX + (X^TX)^T)\beta
$$
where if we have a symmetric matrix this becomes e.g. $(X^TX)^T = X^TX$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\beta^TX^TX\beta  = 2X^TX\beta
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. However, I am looking for something like $\frac{\partial (x^TAX)}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: sorry it was not clear from your question - the other answer contains a component wise explanation.